# How to run all tests in a single driver

Tags: java, selenium

At present time i am closing my browser after test has been executed then when another browser runs i get an error saying invalid session.

I would like to keep a single browser open a to be able to run all the tests.

Here is my Settings

```java
public class WebDriverSettings {
    
    protected static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/....");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        loginToDevEnvironment();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.close();
        }
    }


Here is two test and at present time i can only run one successfully and if i run both it happens that browser gets reopened and i also get invalid session id error

    public class LoginServiceTest extends WebDriverSettings {

    private LoginService loginService;
    private HomePageService homePageService;

    @Before
    @Override
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        loginService = LoginService.loginServiceInstance(driver);
        homePageService = HomePageService.homePageServiceInstance(driver);
        CookieService cookieService = CookieService.cookieServiceInstance(driver);
        cookieService.acceptCookies();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDisplayErrorMessageIfCredentialsAreIncorrect(){
        homePageService.clickOnMyAccountTab();
        loginService.login("wrong-email","test");
        Assert.assertEquals("Your login details are incorrect.",loginService.incorrectCredentialsErrorMessage());
    }
    

    @Test
    public void shouldSuccessfullyLogin()  {
        homePageService.clickOnMyAccountTab();
        loginService.login("", "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the ***@After*** annotation and update accordingly.
If you are using TestNG refer to this TestNG annotations document: https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

> @AfterClass: The annotated method will be run after all the test methods in the current class have been run.

***@AfterClass*** annotation might be suitable for this specific query of yours